# How to hide a div based on its class

Tags: html, css

Can someone please show me how I am able to hide a div based on class, or an image based on its name using CSS? I have the following code below but I am not sure how to hide it as the div doesn't have an id. I am unable to delete or modify this code, hence why I am asking how to hide it. Many thanks.

```
<div class="jicons-icons">
<img alt="Miscellaneous Information: " src="/media/contacts/images/con_info.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Are the answers below doesn't work well for you? what exactly you want to do?

Comment: First one does thanks. I wasn't sure how to change a class in CSS. Now I do :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide a div with a class :

```
.jicons-icons {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/vnng4nf3/

```
img[alt="foobar"] {
    display: none;
}
```